# building a dynamic form with checkboxes with nested data

Tags: angular, typescript

Trying to create a dynamic list of checkboxes with angular to use in a form with nested data but its not working. How would you setup the class logic for this?

**dataset**

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'lorem ipsum class',
        uuid: 'x-123-v'
        goals: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'class one'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'class two'
            },
            { ... }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'more class',
        uuid: '199-c-c'
        goals: [
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'class three'
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'class four'
            }
            { ... }
        ]
    },
    { ... }
]
```

**html component**

```
<app-form (submitted)="submit()" [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <div class="goal__container" *ngFor="let cluster of dataSet">
        <h5>{{cluster.title}} {{cluster.uuid}}</h5>
        <div *ngFor="let goal of cluster">
            <label>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    class="form-control"
                    [formControl]="goal.id"
                />
                {{goal.name}}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</app-form>
```

**class component**

```
export class PlannerComponent {
    public formGroup: FormGroup;
}
```

Comment: I can be mistaken, but I think checkboxes only return true/false. Maybe use `radio-buttons`, instead of checkboxes.

Comment: why isn't it working? you are using reactive forms it seems. Did you create a formGroup and added the import of `ReactiveFormsModule`?

Comment: Yes checkboxes return a bool which is fine, cant use radio buttons as they are not a group and can contain one or more values

Comment: yes those are present

Comment: can you show me the code for your formGroup :)!

Answer (score 0):

Try using Reactive forms, this is basic skeleton you will need to pad it out

bit messy done in a hurry but you should get the idea:

Typscript

```
        invoiceForm: FormGroup;
        
        constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
        this.invoiceForm = this.fb.group({
              
             //other forms controls
             //...
        
              parts: this.fb.array([]),
            });
        }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
    
      [yourarray].forEach((element) => {
                this.addPart();
              });
    
              this.invoiceForm.patchValue(this.loadedInvoice);
    }
    
      /**
       *
       */
      addPart(): void {
        this.countParts++;
    
        let g = this.fb.group({
          id: ['', Validators.required],
          title: ['', Validators.required],
          uuid: ['', Validators.required],
        });
    
        let a = this.invoiceForm.get('parts') as FormArray;
        a.push(g);
    
        ToolsService.log('parts', a);
      }
  /**
   *
   */
  getParts(): FormArray {
    let a = this.invoiceForm.get('parts') as FormArray;
    return a;
  }
```

Markup

```
<form [formGroup]="invoiceForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">


 //other form stuff
  //...

    <ng-container
      formArrayName="parts"
      *ngFor="let part of getParts()['controls']; let i = index"
    >
      <div [formGroupName]="i" class="p-fluid grid formgrid">
        <div class="field col-6 md:col-2">
          <label for="pname">Code*</label>
          <input id="pname" type="checkbox" formControlName="id" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>

</form>
```